# How to implement google map in codeingiter applications?

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps

I tried to use Google Map inside my Codeigniter Application but i didn't find any solution on the net
to give me a detailed explanation.

how can I implement Google Map in Codeigniter?

and how do i customize it according to my needs?

Answer (score 0):

I have personally used the following library:

[codeigniter library](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library)!

There is also documentation included.